# REGEX: construct regex involving optional characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to construct regex on the following patterns
1. abc 24 defZ 
2. abc lmnZ 
3. pqrZ

The idea here is to extract characters preceding Z in that word. Z is the constant characters where the rest are random characters. For the examples shown above, I need the following 
1. def
2. lmn
3. pqr

I know I can use normal string operation but its important that this is the regex.
The regex that I have  is :

```
(\s*)?(.*)Z
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex which extracts the characters you want by looking ahead for `Z` at the end of the String.

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?=Z$)
```

Comment: For the example abc 24defZ  (observe no space between the number and def). how do you extract def

Comment: if you want to extract only letters then use `[a-zA-Z]+(?=Z)`

Comment: I should have been more clear early on..I have korean characters in place of english characters..for ex:1. a 9공룡Z or 2. a 공룡Z. I want to extract all the characters before 'Z' until we find a space or a numeric character. In these examples .. I am trying to extract 공룡

Answer (score 1):

Use `\S` to match one or more non-spacer characters.

```
\S+(?=Z)
```

OR

This also matches an empty string exists before `Z` in this `foo Zbar` string.

```
\S*(?=Z)
```

OR

Use capturing group.

```
(\S+)Z
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jS0iI1/5)

If you want to extract only letters then use

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?=Z)
```